# Why are these tractates, "Yeshivish Mesechtos"?

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, yeshiva-school

There is a cycle of tractates in the Talmud that are learned in Yeshiva each year. This is an exclusive list, where only a small number of volumes are covered in the curriculum.

There must be some reason for the choices on the list, and why other mesechtos were excluded. So: Why were those specific tractates chosen? What are the characteristics that make them fit for this list?

Comment: follow up question.. why with the invention of lifetime kollel was the curriculum not expanded?

Comment: @Avi feel free to ask that as a separate question. But in many Kollels I know, this doesn't apply

Comment: @avi, For the lifetime kollels, even the non-lifetime kollels, the curriculum *was* expanded. For any *masechta* you wish to learn, there is a kollel doing it, even if you might be hard-pressed to find a yeshiva that is.

Comment: @avi I think "lifetime kolels" have been around for 1000's of years.

Comment: @HachamGabriel you would be most certainly wrong though.  It's a new invention made possible by modern economics and governments.

Comment: @avi what about the members of the Sanhedrin?

Comment: @HachamGabriel What about them?  They worked for a living.

Comment: "lifetime kollel" - Nah. As mentioned above, once people have finished these masechtos, or really whenever they want, there are chaburos that move into the more semicha-based masechtos like Shabbos, Chullin and Niddah. And others that do Kodoshim... And eventually some doing Choshen Mishpat. (All at Ner Israel, in the Ezras Nashim area.)

Comment: Btw, I'd like to know why the Brisk yeshivos only do Kodoshim. Why is that a good idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of my *rabbeim*, who was a student of [R' Elya Svei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elya_Svei) explained this to me as follows:

The yeshiva curriculum includes *masechtos* from *nashim* and *nezikin*, such as *Yevamos, Kesuvos, Gittin, Kiddushin, Bava Kama, Bava Metzia, Bava Basra* etc. for two main reasons:

- There are classic commentaries on Talmud Bavli, and these *masechtos* include more of the commentaries that are beneficial in developing a learning methodology than all the other *masechtos*.
- These *masechtos* include many *sugyos* that are central to the rest of *shas* and involve a lot of cross referencing and ideas that come up in many other *masechtos*.

Since the studies in yeshivos are intended to influence the way a person learns for the remainder of his life, these considerations are important in choosing the yeshiva curriculum.

Comment: Especially Masechet Ketubot, which is sometimes referred to as "Shas Katan," IIRC.

Comment: Regarding your first bullet point, I always thought the causality was the other way around: there are more sefarim on these mesechtos because they are studied by more people

Comment: @Yitzchak, Interesting point. I can't think of why the "yeshivish" masechtos would be more popular in the times of the rishonim such that e.g. Rabbeinu Yonah would write his commentary on only such masechtos. In my mind, it's caused more by the second bullet point. In other words, since these masechtos have central sugyas and important concepts, more commentaries were decided to be written on them in favor of the others. Then that gained them more popularity in the later yeshiva world.

Comment: @Jake You answered your own question. They were more popular because they contained central sugyos, specifically central sugyos related to practical halacha

Comment: @Yitzchak, That's a possibility, although not what I meant. I didn't mean that those *masechtos* were necessarily more popular, just that given the chance to write a commentary on a *masechta*, Rishon X would choose e.g. Bava Basra rather than e.g. Shabbos, since it would be more beneficial in explaining his views on a wider range of applicable sugyos. Perhaps this phenomenon caused the later popularity of these *masechtos*.