# Classic Achronim and Rishonim

Tags: talmud-gemara, rabbis

People often say they learn Shas with Achronim and Rishonim. I'm curious, what are the mainstream Rishonim and Achronim that are generally learnt throughout Shas?

Comment: It's not opinion based. It's more or less become a fact. But I'm not sure what that fact is. So enlighten me please, thank you.

Comment: wouldn't the basics be the ones included in a printing of a gemara?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62100/what-texts-are-studied-in-a-traditional-yeshiva

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the person, but the most common that are on most masechtos are:

Rishonim: Besides Rashi and Tosafos: Rif, Ramban, Rashba, Rosh, Ran, Ritva, Tosafos HaRosh, Nimukei Yosef.

Acharonim: Maharsha, Pnei Yehoshua, R' Akiva Eiger, Chasam Sofer, Rashash, Aruch LaNer, Toras Chayim, Kovetz Shiurim.

Also there are often major works that are only on a few masechtos, but are used pretty frequently there. For example, Hamakneh on Kiddushin, Hafla'ah of Kesubos, Turei Even, Yashreish Yaakov and Kovetz Hearos on Yevamos, Nachalas David.

This is not meant to be an exhaustive list. I am sure that there are many others deserving to be on this list.

Comment: Is Rabbenu Elyakim, Meiri, Rabbenu Peretz, Tosfos HaRid, mainstream?

Comment: Is Ben Yehoyada Mainstream?

Comment: If by mainstream you mean accepted, yes. However, if someone said he learns with Rishonim and Acharonim, I wouldn't assume he necessarily meant them. As far as Ben Yehoyada, it is written on Aggadic parts of Talmud, and the people in your question tend to focus on the halachic parts of Gemara.

Answer (score 1):

This is a list of mainstream mefarshim. This doesn't mean people learn every single peirush they said. Maybe every Tosafos and Rashi. But not the rest.
Reishonim.
Rashi. Tosafos. Shita Mikubetzes. Rashba. Ran on some meschtas.These are most common.
Others are still mainstream though. Like Ramban. Rosh. Ritva. Tosafos Rosh. Tosafos Rabeinu Peretz.

Achronim mainstream.
Maharsha . Maharam, Pnei Yehoshua.