# Tosafot Peirush

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, torah-study, rashi, tosfot

I am looking for a sefer that offers an in depth explanation of tosafos (and preferably rashi) to aid me in studying in depth on my own. The ideal would be to have it in english, but a hebrew explanation would suffice as well. My question is what are my options for such a sefer, and which option is the most comprehensive and clear.

Comment: Though not close to complete, http://www.tosfosinenglish.com/ does cover some of the more common sugyos from [mesechtos that are learned in Yeshivos](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11135/883). There's a physical edition, though I don't think many stores carry it. See also this question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40323/what-are-some-good-resources-for-deciphering-a-tosfos-comment-that-i-cant-figur

Comment: Iyun hadaf  has tosfos for many mashectot

Comment: @HodofHod Is that not a dupe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mesivta is a running Hebrew commentary with footnotes which includes a full explanation of Rashi Tosfos and the major issues and how the Rishonim and Achronim deal with it

It has about 120 volumes covering all of Shas.

You can view some of its features here http://www.oz-vehadar.com/en/department/16/editions-of-the-metivta

Answer (score 3):

The Daf Yomi Advancement Forum - [dafyomi.co.il](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/) - has an English point-by-point translation of every Tosfos in the Maseches, in its entirety.

They cover the entire Shas until the end of Avoda Zara - and I'm sure they are working on the last few Mesachtot.

Each Tosfos starts with a summary, and then each phrase is brought in the original and then explained in English.

Comment: This seems to be an excellent resource, but it is not true that every masechta before avoda zarah is covered. Sadly the one I need is not.

Comment: There's also the מי מנוחות on many מסכתות

Comment: It is missing maseches kidushin

Comment: They emailed me informing me that: _Meanwhile you can access the Tosfos here 
http://www.dafyomi.co.il/kidushin/tosqaindex.htm

We are working on a more permanent solution still._

Answer (score 2):

There is a set of Shaarei Tosafos which explains each Tosafos, in Hebrew, really well.

Answer (score 1):

Mei Menuchos, by Rabbi Nachman Kahana, is a clear and systematic explanation of Tosfos (in Hebrew), and is available free online for several mesechtos:

http://nachmankahana.com/mei-menuchos/

Answer (score 0):

Artscroll has many but not all tosfos explained in footnotes.