# Tosfos commentaries available online

Tags: product-recommendation, tosfot

‏Could anybody recommend a good book or website available online for free which explains hard points in Tosfos?

I would prefer something on Hebrewbooks. I know that Daf Yomi Kollel features a nice English translation, but that is bringing only the pshat, and not the complex issues.

Comment: I suppose if you really wanted a detailed explanation, you'd need to go for the hard copy version of ArtScroll or תוספות המבואר in Hebrew.

Comment: Mei Menachos ,should be a few available online for free.

Comment: The classic is https://www.sefaria.org.il/texts/Talmud/Bavli/Acharonim%20on%20Talmud/Chidushei%20Halachot

Comment: Best answer could vary by masechta.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I found that this has been asked (twice) already: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65573/tosafot-peirush

Comment: In my experience, when a Tosfos isn't discussed by the Maharsha, Maharam and Pnei Yehoshua, the Kikayon DeYona does bring it down and explain it. K"dY is also available on hebrewbooks

Answer (score 5):

http://www.tosfosinenglish.com/

They do an amazing job explaining tosfofs. They go line by line explaning each frase and will bring down any relevant gammarah that you need for that tosfos They dont have on the whole shas mostly just on the yeshiva meschtas. The best part is that its free and you can print it. I found it very helpful in my days in high school.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for everyone, in the meantime I found very useful the sefer **Bircas Avraham** from *HaRav Erlanger* which is available on Hebrewbooks for many masechtot and provides great insights.

Answer (score -1):

This site does a nice job in explaining Tosfos https://dafyomi.co.il

Comment: This is mentioned in the OP as being something the OP wasn't looking for.