# Is it true that most Haredi Yeshivas focus on only (the same) one of the sedorim?

Tags: talmud-gemara, yeshiva-school

I heard from a Haredi yeshiva-bocher, and confirmed with another, that  most Haredi yeshivos learn only one of the   sedorim (or maybe it was one of the masechtos), and that it is the *same one* across almost all yeshivos (with a few outlier yeshivos known for  specializing in another one).

This was quite surprising.

Is it true?

If so, which seder (or masechto) is it?

Comment: Very related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11135/15256

Comment: Thank you. So (almost) the only sedorim studied are  Nashim and Nezikin, and from these specifically the masechtos  Yevamos, Kesuvos, Gittin, Kiddushin, Badva Kama, Bava Metzia, Bava Basra. Is that correct?

Comment: @JoshuaFox chabad yeshivas add shabbos to their “cycle”

Comment: This only considers *iyun seder*. Many yeshivos, esp. high school, also have bekius masechtas like sukkah, brachos, megillah, etc.

Comment: Anecdotal, but I went to a chareidi, litvish yeshiva and in my first year there the yeshiva was doing Pesachim b'iyun ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: One thing missing from the discussion here and at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11135/15256 is that many yeshivos include nedarim into the nashim masechtos when doing their nashim/nezikin cycle.  Also I have noticed makkos added into nezikin.

Comment: Pesachim too. (Ner Israel, Mir) And a little Sanhedrin thrown in (בן סורר ומורה).

Comment: As you can see above there is no one set list despite what anyone says, but there are clearly a lot of choices that are more common.

Answer (score 1):

See Gemara Berachos 20a "in the years of Rav Yehuda all of their learning was confined to just the learning of Seder Nezikin.

Comment: While this is indeed a great answer with a solid source, I think the OP is asking about yeshivas in our time.